# Sql compare tables / full outer join with filter on both sides

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, outer-join

**Real world case**

I have a table (in MS SQL Server) which has the following columns:
AccountId, RunId and Details

I want to compare 2 'runs' and find the differences between runs.

To simplify the case, I made the following sample.

**Simplified case**

```
CREATE TABLE #T (
    AccountId INT NOT NULL,
    RunId INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #T
(AccountId , RunId)
VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 2),
(3, 1)
DROP TABLE #T
```

**Desired output (; seperated)**

```
AccountId;Run1;Run2
2;NULL;2
3;1;NULL
```

**Working solutions so far**

1:

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.AccountId, T2.AccountId) [AccountId], T1.RunId [Run1], T2.RunId [Run2]
FROM #T T1
FULL OUTER JOIN #T T2 ON T2.AccountId = T1.AccountId AND T2.RunId = 2 AND T1.RunId = 1
WHERE (T1.RunId = 1 OR T1.RunId IS NULL)
AND (T2.RunId = 2 OR T2.RunId IS NULL)
AND (T1.AccountId IS NULL OR T2.AccountId IS NULL)
ORDER BY [AccountId]
```

2:

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.AccountId, T2.AccountId) [AccountId], T1.RunId [Run1], T2.RunId [Run2]
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 0 [0]) AS [T0]
FULL OUTER JOIN #T T1 ON T1.RunId = 1
FULL OUTER JOIN #T T2 ON T2.AccountId = T1.AccountId AND T2.RunId = 2 AND [0] = 0
WHERE ([0] = 0 OR T2.RunId = 2)
AND (T1.AccountId IS NULL OR T2.AccountId IS NULL)
ORDER BY [AccountId]
```

3:

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.AccountId, T2.AccountId) [AccountId], T1.RunId [Run1], T2.RunId [Run2]
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM #T WHERE #T.RunId = 1
) T1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM #T WHERE #T.RunId = 2
) T2 ON T2.AccountId = T1.AccountId
WHERE (T1.AccountId IS NULL OR T2.AccountId IS NULL)
```

**My actual question**

All three solutions are rather ugly. Isn't there an easier way?

If not, which of the three do you think is best?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
select accountid, min(runid)
from t
where runid in (1, 2)
group by accountid
having count(*) = 1;
```

This will show you the accounts only in one run, along with the run they are in.

Comment: This works fine with the tiny table example I gave.
The real world example has a details column. I'd like to query that too.

Comment: @WVPM . . . It is only possible to answers the question that you actually ask.  This answers your question.  If you have a *different* question, ask it as a *new* question.  This is particularly important when a question already has answers, because changing the question can invalidate answers, which draws downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

My everyday solution for comparing two identical tables is:

```
-- t1 rows not in t2
select * from t1
except
select * from t2

-- t2 rows not in t1
select * from t2
except
select * from t1
```